# Dependency Injection and Singleton. Are they two entirely different concepts?

Tags: c#, architecture, singleton

I've been hearing about using the dependency injection over Singleton for my colleague. I still can't make out if it they are two orthogonal patterns which can be replaced with one another? Or is DI a method to make the Singleton pattern testable?

Please take a look at the following code snippet.

```
    IMathFace obj = Singleton.Instance;

    SingletonConsumer singConsumer = new SingletonConsumer(obj);

    singConsumer.ConsumerAdd(10,20);
```

The `SingletonConsumer` is accepting a parameter of type `IMathFace`. Instead of accessing the singleton class internally, `SingletonConsumer` will get the singleton instance passed by the caller. Is this a good example of consuming singleton class via dependency injection?

Comment: Can you please tell me how DI can replace the singleton?

Comment: Singleton is a design pattern.  DI/IoC is a technique.

Comment: DI cannot replace Singleton any more than a banana could replace a carburetor.  They're completely different concepts.

Comment: so my example is valid.

Comment: Yes, it's valid, the question is, why would you do it? what's the use cass of passing the Singleton instance to the consumer?

Comment: So i can inject mock objects instead of  original singleton instance while unit testing

Comment: Yes, but it may come on the expense of encapsulation (which is also true for non-singleton) see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005473/must-dependency-injection-come-at-the-expense-of-encapsulation

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think he meant that you should use dependency injection to inject a single instance of the service, instead of using the classical Singleton implementation with a static accessor `MySingleton.Instance`.

```
public class MySingleton
{
    public static MySingleton Instance{get{...}};
}
```

With the classical singleton implementation all your code depends on that service being a singleton. You basically hardcode that assumption into consuming code whenever you use `MySingleton.Instance`.

On the other hand with DI you get an instance of the service passed into your constructor, and store it. That there is only a single instance of this service is an implementation detail. You can easily change it to give the consuming code a different instance. That way you have some class/interface which happens to be implemented by a single instance, instead of enforcing that there is only one instance.

This is useful if you for example want a mock implementation of the service for testing, or if different parts of the program need different configurations of that service.

Answer (score 5):

There is one case where the Singleton pattern and DI/IoC intersect- the injection of a Singleton.

Most DI frameworks can be configured to instantiate a single instance of an injected object.  Any consumer object that requests an instance of such an object will get the same single instance.  That instance is by definition a Singleton.  That's about it for the overlap in concept.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are right. Instead of accessing the object via the singleton, you are passing a reference to it thus you're using a constructor injection.

What others point out is that these notions are not related. Consuming a singleton instance is nothing special as the object you are injecting to doesn't really care where the injected object comes from.

Answer (score 2):

The confusion here is that two concepts have been conflated: the singleton and the static accessor/gateway to the singleton instance.

As you have rightly identified, your colleague is suggesting that the dependency be injected rather than accessed directly using `Singleton.Instance` (static gateway).

The reason that this has nothing really to do with the singleton pattern is that the same DI concept applies equally to instantiating a non-singleton object with `new Foo()`. The dependency would be injected irrespective of whether it is a singleton implementation.